# An authorized user can view other authorized page because of setAuthCookie

Tags: asp.net

I'm working on an asp.net application. it consist of two modules:

1. End Users
2. Managers

I've built both modules and integrated it into one. Now comes the question, I verify the end user from a database and issue permissions to the user to view members-only resources by

```
setAuthCookie()
```

When the user presses the logout button it will automatically logout by

```
signout()
```

while I was going through with stuff, I came to know that an end user also views manager side of application because he is authorized to view and I authorized him by 'sethAuthCookie'.
(when user request login page i.e for manager and for end user, it will redirect to some action page which I also do in page_load event by 'httpcontext.current.request.isauthorized').

The above is also valid in case of a manager.

Is there any way that an end user can view only his side of application? vice versa

Possible solutions came to my mind:

1. Create a cookie which stores an encrypted form user type i.e he is manager or end user and check it in page_load event.
2. store it in some session variable

These both are insecure and very hard coded.

Is there any way to resolve this problem using some built-in or rich approach ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are talking about [Role Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5k850zwb(v=vs.100).aspx). It is built-in. Customizing your own version isn't difficult either.

Comment: Hey @MikeSmithDev
I think it would need "application services" database? I dont want to use that.
Suggestions ?
And thanks in advance

Comment: Normally yes you store roles in a database. I assume you already have one because you have an authentication system. While I normally like a `Roles` table, you *could* just add a Role column to your `Users` table. This only gets to be a problem if people can have multiple roles. If you aren't using a database, you can still do this, just make a custom [RoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that sets Roles based on whatever criteria you have.

Comment: aah! Seems logical. I have 3 types of users: 1. end user, 2. employees, 3. manager. Managers can do everything, end users have limited access.
Please post it as answer, what to do in web.config, in database and some hints about role class
Thanks!!